# Where clause for categorical variable in R using RSQLite

Tags: r, sqlite

I'm using RSQLite to access a simple SQLite database to return a defined set of data. I want to be able to limit the query so that I return only a subset of the data by limiting on a categorical field.

I have written a function that I would like to be able to supply with the parameter to be used  in the where clause, but when I run it that way with the value as a parameter I keep getting an 'object 'AAPL' found error' (where the parameter is AAPL).

By hard-coding in the value I want to limit on within the function it works fine, and running `f2(5)` will return the first 5 rows for 'AAPL'

```
f2 <- function(n, stockName) {

  library(RSQLite)

  conSQLiteParallel <- dbConnect("SQLite", dbname="stocks.sqlite")
  ## this sql works fine
  sqlcmdParallel <- paste("SELECT stock, gain ",
      "FROM stock_gains ",
      "WHERE day <=", n, " and stock ='AAPL'", sep="")
  resultsHandleParallel <- dbSendQuery(conSQLiteParallel, sqlcmdParallel)

  d <- fetch(resultsHandleParallel)
}

results <- f2(5)
```

However when I try to pass the value to the function using the stockName variable it gives me

```
f2 <- function(n, stockName) {

    library(RSQLite)
    conSQLiteParallel <- dbConnect("SQLite", dbname="stocks.sqlite")
    ## this sql does not work correctly, but only gives an error 
    ## when running the function
    sqlcmdParallel <- paste("SELECT stock, gain ",
        "FROM stock_gains ",
         "WHERE stock =", stockName, sep="")
    resultsHandleParallel <- dbSendQuery(conSQLiteParallel, sqlcmdParallel)

    d <- fetch(resultsHandleParallel)
}

results <- f2(5,APPL) - gives the error "Error in paste("SELECT stock, gain FROM stock_gains WHERE stock =", stockName,  : 
  object 'APPL' not found"

results <- f2(5,'APPL') - gives the error "Error in sqliteExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: no such column: APPL) "

results <- f2(5,distinctStocks[1,1]) - gives the error "Error in sqliteExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: no such column: AAPL) "
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated as I'm getting a little frustrated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stockName` should be be in quotes:

```
paste0("SELECT stock, gain FROM stock_gains WHERE day <= ", n, 
       " and stock = '", stockName, "'")
```

This also should work:

```
library(gsubfn)
fn$identity("SELECT stock, gain 
             FROM stock_gains 
             WHERE day <= $n and stock = '$stockName'")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had already tried the first option, but it gives me the following error: Error in paste("SELECT stock, gain FROM stock_gains WHERE day <= ", n,  : 
  object 'APPL' not found

Comment: The second option works great. I just need to run it this way with the stock name in quotes then: results <- f2(5,'AAPL') Thanks for your help

Comment: The first one should work too. Maybe you left out the single quotes around stockName?

Comment: Actually the error I posted in the first comment was due to a typo as it should have been 'AAPL', but when I ran it again there it runs without error, but the query doesn't return any result:
> results <- f2(5,'AAPL')
> results
[1] stock gain 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
I'm more than happy to go with the second option though as it works just fine